# Too many connections issue with postgres and multiprocessing

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to read and write to a db in the following way:

```
with open("argument_file.txt", "r") as f:
    arguments = f.read().split("\n")
engine = create_engine('postgresql://...', pool_size=20, max_overflow=0)
with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=20, initializer=lambda : engine.dispose(close=False)) as e:
    for result in e.map(main, arguments):
        print(result)

def main(argument):
    metadata = s.MetaData()
    events = Table('events', metadata, autoload_with=engine)
    query = select(events).where(...)  
    with engine.connect() as connection:
        ResultProxy = connection.execute(query)
        df = pd.DataFrame(ResultProxy.fetchall())
        df.columns = ResultProxy.keys()
    transformed_df = f(df)
    transformed_df.to_sql("table_name", engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
    return f"Argument {argument} processed"
```

(`f` is a function that maps a `pd.DataFrame` to a `pd.DataFrame`.) I am running into an error `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already`. When checking `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;` I am seeing many old idle processes (the most I have seen is 96, which could explain that there is an issue with a pool size of 20 and a maximum of 115 connections in postgresql).

I suspect that there is an issue with closing old connections. But I think my code closes (either via context manager or via `pd` built-in code). What am I missing? (If this way to read/write is suboptimal in other ways, I'd also be very happy to hear that!)

Comment: You must think wrongly. There has to be a connection leak in your code.